# GTK/Python: How to get key-press-event to edit and navigate a TreeView cell?

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, keypress

I've connected to the "key-press-event" to navigate through a Gtk.TreeView. I successfully got *Tab* to navigate to the right (across a row). I'm having trouble with using *Return* to navigate downwards. When a cell is selected I can edit its contents but I have to press *Return* once to commit the value and again to navigate to the cell below. I would like the behaviour to be like the *Tab* where I press *Return* once and the change is committed and the selected cell moves down one. I'm gunning for behaviour like that of a spreadsheet.

I'm guessing there is a conflict here with key bindings, i.e., the first *Return* press event commits the changes and the second *Return* press event navigates downwards. Also, I tried connecting the *Shift_L* key (instead of *Return*) to navigate downwards and while it navigates with one press it also fails to commit the changes to the cell.

I'll whip up a MWE if need be but I figure someone out there might know the issue here and could point me in the right direction or educate me.

**EDIT:** Okay, I took the time and stripped everything down to a MWE that can be tested/eyeballed by anyone able to help. The pertinent section of code is the callback function named *onTreeNavigateKeyPress*. Within that, the troublesome condition is the *elif keyname == 'Return'*. If you run this on your machine you'll see that you can change the cell value and *Tab* to the right and the *Tab* both navigates rightward and commits the changed value to the cell. Doing the same with the *Return* key will commit the change but you'll need to press *Return* again to navigate downwards. Call me pedantic but I hate that. As you can see from the code I have tried calling the *Gtk.TreeView.set_cursor* method directly with the new location as well as calling it from a [new thread using *Glib.timeout_add*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497766/python-pygoobject-treeview-confirm-edit-after-move-between-cells-with-tab-key).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3`

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib


class linFitApp(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='Testing Keypress Events on Treeview')
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)
        self.set_border_width(5)

        self.mainBox = Gtk.Box()
        self.scrollTableWindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrollTableWindow.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        self.mainBox.pack_start(self.scrollTableWindow, False, False, 0)
        self.add(self.mainBox)

        ############################################################################


        #Now to set up the data table
        self.dataTableListStore = Gtk.ListStore(float, float, float, float)
        self.dataTableTreeView = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.dataTableListStore)
        self.dataTableTreeView.props.activate_on_single_click = True
        self.dataTableTreeView.connect("key-press-event", self.onTreeNavigateKeyPress)

        #set up the x column
        self.xColumnTextRenderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.xColumnTextRenderer.set_property("editable", True)
        self.xColumnTextRenderer.connect("edited", self.onXChanged)
        self.xColumnTreeView = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("x", self.xColumnTextRenderer, text=0)

        #set up the y column
        self.yColumnTextRenderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.yColumnTextRenderer.set_property("editable", True)
        self.yColumnTextRenderer.connect("edited",self.onYChanged)
        self.yColumnTreeView = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("y", self.yColumnTextRenderer, text=1)

        #set up the dx column
        self.dxColumnTextRenderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.dxColumnTextRenderer.set_property("editable", True)
        self.dxColumnTextRenderer.connect("edited",self.onDxChanged)
        self.dxColumnTreeView = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("dx", self.dxColumnTextRenderer, text=2)

        #set up the dy column
        self.dyColumnTextRenderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.dyColumnTextRenderer.set_property("editable", True)
        self.dyColumnTextRenderer.connect("edited",self.onDyChanged)
        self.dyColumnTreeView = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("dy", self.dyColumnTextRenderer, text=3)

        #pack treeview into the scrolled window
        self.scrollTableWindow.add(self.dataTableTreeView)

        #add treeview columns to treeview
        self.dataTableTreeView.append_column(self.xColumnTreeView)
        self.dataTableTreeView.append_column(self.yColumnTreeView)
        self.dataTableTreeView.append_column(self.dxColumnTreeView)
        self.dataTableTreeView.append_column(self.dyColumnTreeView)

        #fill in treeview with some sample data
        self.dataTableListStore.append([0, 4, 0, 0])
        self.dataTableListStore.append([5, 8.2, 0, 0])
        self.dataTableListStore.append([10, 11.7, 0, 0])
        self.dataTableListStore.append([15, 16.5, 0, 0])
        self.dataTableListStore.append([20, 19, 0, 0])
        self.dataTableListStore.append([25, 24.5, 0, 0])
        self.dataTableListStore.append([30, 26.2, 0, 0])



    #define the callbacks for cell editing
    def onXChanged(self, widget, path, number):
        self.dataTableListStore[path][0]=float(number.replace(',', '.'))

    def onYChanged(self, widget, path, number):
        self.dataTableListStore[path][1]=float(number.replace(',', '.'))

    def onDxChanged(self, widget, path, number):
        self.dataTableListStore[path][2]=float(number.replace(',', '.'))

    def onDyChanged(self, widget, path, number):
        self.dataTableListStore[path][3]=float(number.replace(',', '.'))

    #define the callback for keypress events
    def onTreeNavigateKeyPress(self, treeview, event):
        keyname = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
        path, col = treeview.get_cursor()
        columns = [c for c in treeview.get_columns()] 
        colnum = columns.index(col)        

        if keyname == 'Tab':

            if colnum + 1 < len(columns):
                next_column = columns[colnum + 1]
            else: 
                next_column = columns[0]
            GLib.timeout_add(50,
                             treeview.set_cursor,
                             path, next_column, True)


        elif keyname == 'Return':

            model = treeview.get_model()
            #Check if currently in last row of Treeview
            if path.get_indices()[0] + 1 == len(model):
                path = treeview.get_path_at_pos(0,0)[0]
                #treeview.set_cursor(path, columns[colnum], True)
                GLib.timeout_add(50,
                             treeview.set_cursor,
                             path, columns[colnum], True)
            else:
                path.next()
                #treeview.set_cursor(path, columns[colnum], True)
                GLib.timeout_add(50,
                             treeview.set_cursor,
                             path, columns[colnum], True)
        else:
            pass


#create main application window and start Gtk loop
mainWindow = linFitApp()
mainWindow.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
mainWindow.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: UPDATE: I placed a print statement into the callback function that catches Return key presses and it looks like I'm catching only every second key press. The key press that commits the value to the cell is not emitting a *key-press-event* signal. What to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer (maybe just a functional hack) is as follows:

Pressing Return while a Gtk.Treeview cell is in editing mode does not release the key-press-event signal. Instead of connecting my callback function to the *key-press-event* signal I connect it to the *key-release-event* signal which **is** emitted after Return is pressed while a cell is being edited. So pressing the Return key will activate whichever signal it does to commit a new value (I still don't know which signal that is) and releasing the Return key will activate the navigation to the next cell. Voila, we have the two desired actions resulting from a single press of the Return key.

**Short answer:**

Change this

```
self.dataTableTreeView.connect("key-press-event", self.onTreeNavigateKeyPress)
```

to this

```
self.dataTableTreeView.connect("key-release-event", self.onTreeNavigateKeyPress)
```